# Azure Log Analytics switch statement / pattern matching

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I'm trying to process my **Application Insights** data using Application Insights Analytics and Log **Analytics Query Language**. What I'd like to have is something like switch statement in C# or pattern matchng in F#. So the pseudocode would be like this:

```
requests
| where timestamp > now(-1d)
| project endpoint = (switch(name){ {case: "POST /api/jobs/search", then: "Jobs Search"}, {case: "POST /api/offices/search", then: "Office Search"} ...})
```

Or maybe there is some kind of workaround to define a dictionary-like structure and then use that structure in my query

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [case() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/casefunction).

```
requests
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| project endpoint = case(
    name == "POST /api/jobs/search", "Jobs Search",
    name == "POST /api/offices/search", "Office Search",
    "Unknown")
```

Comment: Thank you @joaqo, that's what I was looking for